# Преобразовать байтовую строку в байты

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно, не совсем удачная формулировка заголовка вопроса. Сервер возвращает строку вида

```
b'\x80\x04\x95\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94(\x8c\x01e\x94h\x01h\x01e.'
```

Она получена путем

```
pickle.dumps(list("eee"))
```

Вопрос: как сделать

```
"".join(pickle.loads(b'\x80\x04\x95\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94(\x8c\x01e\x94h\x01h\x01e.'))
```

если сервер возвращает строку `b'\x80\x04\x95\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94(\x8c\x01e\x94h\x01h\x01e.'` как `<class str>`?

То есть, строка, по идее, байтовая, но имеет тип `str`. Как привести такую строку к типу `bytes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть такая строка

```
s = r"b'\x80\x04\x95\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94(\x8c\x01e\x94h\x01h\x01e.'"
```

превратить её в bytes можно так:

```
import ast
res = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

https://ideone.com/TcQC6R