# Конвертация байтов в строке в байты

Tags: python

У меня есть строка с байтами (`bytes()`).
Выглядит она примерно так: `b'BM\xbe\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x 00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0 0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x ff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0 0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x 00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\ xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff \xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x0 0\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x 00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0 0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x 00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\ xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0 0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x ff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf f\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x ff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'`. Такой результат можно получить при чтении файла побайтово, или при использовании `bytes(string, 'utf-8')`. Мне нужен тип данных получаемый при работе с этим методом. А не строка. Могу я конвертировать строку в байты (чтобы получить данные обратно)?

Comment: покажите вашу строку с байтами и покажите результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: Какой результат вы ожидаете? О каком типе данных речь?

Comment: Я ожидаю результат в формате bytes. Чтобы получить данные обратно.

Comment: Вы и так показали формат bytes, что не так?

Comment: Это и есть массив байт. Первый байт с ASCII кодом соответсвующим букве `B`, второй - `M`, третий с байтом, которого hex представление `be` и т.д. Массив байт скажем `01 02 03` будет представлен как `b'\x01\x02\x03'`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразовать байтовую строку в байты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170273/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написали в комментариях - это и есть байты, вы просто видите их строковое представление:

```
b = b'BM\xbe\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18' # далее обрезал для краткости
print(type(b))
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'bytes'>
```